# Negative timestamp returned by onNmeaReceived()

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to get real GPS time from onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) callback. But this method returns me a negative timestamp. Is this a bug of GPS Engine or it can be converted to a normal value somehow?

```
@Override
public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NMEA TIMESTAMP: " + timestamp);
        Log.d(TAG, "NMEA MESSAGE:  " + nmea);
}
```

For exmaple - correct time is 1450224000, but returned - -1277879306. Meanwhile, GPS module works fine and returns a correct coordinates in onChangedLocation() callback.

Comment: Did you compare the long with the string? Please post the string too.

Comment: Ahhh.. nevermind... timestamp returned by this callback is not actualy a GPS time. It's system time of fix.